# Insert data in table2 with reference of data in table1

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables named `owners_info`: `id` `unique_id` and `timeinlog`: `timein_id` `id` `time_in`

The `id` in second table is FK of `id` in first table.

The thing is, the `unique_id` is the RFID Tag that reader reads. I just want to insert the time in `time_in` in second table when the TAG is detected by the reader.

**EDIT**

This is what i have now `INSERT INTO timeinlog (timein_id, id, time_in) VALUES (NULL, SELECT id FROM owners_info WHERE u_id = 123, NOW());`

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into timeinlog values (select 'your_timein_id', o.id, 'your_time_in' 
from owners_info o where o.unique_id = 'your_Unique_Id');
```

Comment: Hi, My `timeinlog` table doesn't have yet data. This is what i have now `SELECT id FROM owners_info o WHERE u_id = 123; INSERT INTO timeinlog (timein_id, id, time_in) VALUES (NULL, owners_info.id, NOW());`

Comment: what value will get stored in the timein_id column?
If it is an autoincrement, then, don't pass any value for it. Pass id and now for current time in select statement

Answer (score 0):

I solve it after adding open and close parenthesis.

INSERT INTO timeinlog (timein_id, id, time_in) VALUES (NULL, `(`SELECT id FROM owners_info WHERE u_id = 123`)`, NOW());

Thank you!